# How Select From Parent Based on Child Property in EntityFramework and ESQL

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-sql

I have a parent/child table in Entity Framework and I need to select some row from parent based on child primary key.

I write these code:

```
List<int> s = (from all in DB.TbProfiles
                    where all.TbMaharat.Any(c => maharat.Contains(c.MaharatId))
                    select all.ProfileId).ToList();
```

but I Found that Linq2Entity does not support "Contains", and I must use "MultiSet" and ESQL command. but i can find any sample to do this.

I write ESQL like this but it does not work:

```
byte[] moshTypes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };

        List<int> s =  DB.TbProfiles.Where("it.TbMaharat exists(Select 0 from TbMaharat as e where e.MaharatId IN MultiSet (" + string.Join(",", moshTypes) + "))")
            .Select(c=>c.ProfileId).ToList();

        return s;
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is `maharat` in your first statement?

Comment: "maharat" is array of byte, like second code "moshTypes", they are same

Comment: EF 4 certainly does support `IEnumerable<T>.Contains()`.

Answer (score 0):

To use `IEnumerable<T>.Contains()` method you'd have to load the table into memory using `ToList()` or `ToArray()`. However this can lead to great memory cost so just don't do it unless the table is very small and won't grow in time. 
There is a workaround for `Contains` method: build an `OR` expression for each value so the `Contains()` method becomes `DB.TbMaharat.Where(x=>x.MaharatId == 1 || x.MaharatId == 2 || x.MaharatId == 3)`. See the MSDN thread on how to do this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/ .